Why does the :has pseudo selector not work with a list of elements?
I have a div block with a class "help-image" that contains an <img>, inside a section with a class "help-section".
Using the :has selector as follows works fine:
section.help-section > div:has(img),
section.help-section > div:has(figure),
section.help-section > div:has(button)
{
    background: mistyrose;
}

However, passing a list of elements (as the MDN docs suggest I can) doesn't work at all:
section.help-section > div:has(img, button, figure)
{
    background: mistyrose;
}

I have inspected all elements with the developer tools, and the rule does not appear at all if I use the second example.


section.help-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

div.help-text,
div.help-image {
  flex: 1 0 45%;
  align-self: flex-start;
  min-width: 350px;
}

section.help-section>div:has(img, figure, button) {
  background: mistyrose;
  /* doesn't work in my output */
}
<section class="help-section">
  <div class="help-text">
    <p>This is just an example paragraph, the help-text block will only ever contain text.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="help-image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" />
  </div>
</section>




Does the div have an image and a button and a figure ...? (Provide a proper [mre] please, when you ask this kind of question, and not just snippets that lack context.)

What is the HTML you're trying to select? Please create a runnable example. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#logical_operations

Apologies for the lack of detail, I have added the snippet, which works fine on here, but not in my output, which is very confusing, especially considering the first example in the question continues to work.

Press Ctrl+F5 on your project to see if it's a caching issue. If that doesn't fix it, what browser & version are you using?

@CBroe the comma is an OR not an AND

It's not very clear for me if you want all the <section> to be pink or only the direct <div> children to be pink if they have an <image>, <button> or <figure> tag in them. It's what I supposed, so I changed my answer below.

The pink is just a debug value at the moment to quickly see if the rule has applied. Definitely not a caching issue and I'm using Edge 124.0.2478.67. CanIUse says Edge 124 has full support for the selector and I'm literally only changing the CSS rule I've put in the question, a real head scratcher!...

Have you got another CSS rule setting the background color on this <div>? If yes, what are the specificity (~= weight) of both rules? You can use a specificity calculator to compare them.

@PatrickJanser I just inspected the CSS that was built (I use a program called MadCap Flare) and the rule has been butchered:
section.help-section > div:has(img\00002C\000020figure\00002C\000020button) {  background: mistyrose; } 

Great! Effectively, a bad surprise! I upvoted your answer but can't set it as the correct response. I left my answer, explaining that it is out of scope, but I think it may help other users googling and falling on this :has() and :is() selectors question. I hope you'll find a way to correct the MadCap Flare issue!

Since the original question changed quite a bit, my answer is no
longer valid as I started on some wrong assumptions.
This answer is out of scope, but I'll leave it in case some people
are trying to target a parent element. It can be interesting to
learn about the :has() and the :is() new selectors.
I quickly supposed that you wanted to set a pink background to all
the outer <section class="help-section"> tag if one of the direct
child <div> contained either an <img>, <button> or <figure>
tag. If that was the case, then you could have used the
:is()
CSS selector:
/* Set a pink background to all the help section if one of
   the direct div child contains an img, button or figure. */
.help-section:has(> div :is(img, button, figure))
{
  background: mistyrose;
}

See it in action with an interactive example:


// The button to add an image in the footer, which will have no effect on
// the background of the help section.
document.getElementById('add-image-to-footer').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const footerP = document.querySelector('.help-section footer p');
  
  footerP.innerHTML += ' <img src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/short-term/release/materialsymbolsoutlined/schedule/wght300/20px.svg" alt="time">';
});

// The button to add an image in the content. This should make the
// full help section get pink.
document.getElementById('add-image-to-content').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const contentP = document.querySelector('.help-section-content p:first-child');
  
  contentP.innerHTML =
    '<img src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/short-term/release/materialsymbolsoutlined/menu_book/wght300/20px.svg" alt="book"> ' +
    contentP.innerHTML;
});
/* Set a pink background to all the help section if one of
   the direct div child contains an img, button or figure. */
.help-section:has(> div :is(img, button, figure))
{
  background: mistyrose;
}

/*--------------- Rest of CSS for the POC -----------------*/

.help-section {
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

.help-section-header {
  --heading-font-size: 1.6em;
  --heading-image-size: calc(var(--heading-font-size) * 1.1);
}

.help-section-header h2 {
  font-size: var(--heading-font-size);
  margin: 0;
}

.help-image {
  float: left;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.help-image img {
  width: var(--heading-image-size);
  height: var(--heading-image-size);
}

.help-section footer {
  font-size: .8em;
}

/* All images, except the help image in the header. */
.help-section :not(.help-image) > img {
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.operations {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: .5em;
  align-items: center;
  margin: .5em 0;
}
<section class="help-section">
  <header class="help-section-header">
    <div class="help-image">
      <img src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/short-term/release/materialsymbolsoutlined/help/default/24px.svg"
           alt="Help icon" />
    </div>
    <h2>Help section</h2>
  </header>
  
  <div class="help-section-content">
    <p>This is the help section content.</p>
  </div>
  
  <footer>
    <p>Last update: <time datetime="2024-05-15T19:00">May 15</time></p>
  </footer>
</section>

<div class="operations">
  <button id="add-image-to-footer">
    Add an image to the footer
  </button>
  <small>Should have no effect</small>

  <button id="add-image-to-content">
    Add an image to the content
  </button>
  <small>Should switch the section to pink</small>
</div>



Thanks to Alhci's comment, one cannot nest the :has() selector:
/* This will not work! */
.help-section:has(> div:has(img, button, figure))
{
  background: mistyrose;
}


his selector is targeting a child of .help-section and yours is targeting .help-section. They are not the same, plus his code is working fine.

Yes, I know. It's not very clear what he was wanting to do. I posted a comment about this topic, as you are right, I don't really see the problem with his code, except if it's not doing what he is wanting to do.

it's clear. He posted a first code that does the job (targeting the child of .help-section) and he wanted to try something else that work the same way and it works the same way so the issue is not with the selector

@TemaniAfif Ok, I see. Well, then, as you say, probably an old browser not supporting the :has() selector.

.help-section:has(> div:has(img, button, figure)) This won't work. You can't nest :has.

@Alohci : Ohh! Thanks a lot for the notice! I corrected the answer. I got caught by Chrome's debugger, changing the rule with the nested :is() into the nested :has() and the pink colour stayed. Now I see that changing the rule in the inspector doesn't validate and the previous one stays active, letting you think that your change worked. It's my fault, I didn't read it again.

I use a program called MadCap Flare for publishing help documentation - it appears that this is the culprit and is breaking the CSS rule for some reason:
section.help-section > div:has(img\00002C\000020figure\00002C\000020button)
{
    background: mistyrose;
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
